# Why there is two property named _id and id and only one is visible in object return by mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

When I print the object returned after querying in MongoDB using mongoose I get an object containing one of the keys as '_id'. But when I try to print the object's property id and _id by accessing the object then It doesn't say undefined for the id instead It prints the same id as _id. I am attaching the screenshots for the code and output below.

**Here is the code snippet**

```js
const user = await User.findById(req.params.id);
console.log(user);
console.log(user.id, user._id);
```

**In the following output, we can see that id and _id contains the same value even though there is no property as 'id' available in user object**

```
{
  role: 'user',
  _id: 5fc6cad25884d51790aad697,
  name: 'Test 001',
  email: 'test001@gmail.com',
  __v: 0
}
5fc6cad25884d51790aad697 5fc6cad25884d51790aad697
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the main confusing part for you is `id` where it comes from. Here is explanation from the documentation:

> Mongoose assigns each of your schemas an id virtual getter by default
> which returns the document's _id field cast to a string, or in the
> case of ObjectIds, its hexString. If you don't want an id getter added
> to your schema, you may disable it by passing this option at schema
> construction time.
> `const schema = new Schema({ name: String }, { id: false });`

> Virtuals are document properties that you can get and set but that do not get
> persisted to MongoDB. The getters are useful for formatting or
> combining fields, while setters are useful for de-composing a single
> value into multiple values for storage.

you can read more about it in documentation:

`id` - https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#id

`virtuals` - https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#virtuals

Answer (score 0):

Check that the user object having some instance related issue or not , otherwise it won't happen.